How to Setup Sound for a Live Event and Stream
First off, I am not usually an audio guy. I'm mostly tech, but I've been tasked with setting up both the tech and A/V for a non-profit live event.
Here is the setup: We have two areas next to each other, each with their own speakers and announcers. We are also trying to live stream both events (to two separate YouTube streams). I want to take the audio from both announcers and output them to both the stream and the speakers. I'd also possibly want to take the audio from the cameras and add that to the stream mix. Can I do this with a single mixing board? Also, please keep in mind that we are a non-profit and do not have a ton of money to buy very expensive equipment. We already have speakers and microphones. I'm assuming it's just a mixer that I need. I've done some research, but can't figure out how to take the two separate audio sources and output them to two separate speakers (and the streams).
This is for a Olympic-style weightlifting competition. There are 2 platforms where the "action" takes place. Most of the time the platforms are running concurrently. Each platform has an announcer. What I'm trying to do is capture the audio from each announcer and send it to each live stream, one for each platform. I'm using two cameras, 1 for each platform, but only 1 laptop (running 2 instances of OBS). I was thinking of using camera audio as well (shotgun mics), but that's not completely necessary.

It is slightly unclear if the two events are running at the same time. If they run simultaneously you absolutely need a minimum of two mixers.
An ideal setup would then would be as follows: One front-of-house mixer for event 1 (in the room, hearing the amplified sound). You have to plan ahead on how many inputs you need, maybe only one for the podium mic? If there will be a debate with several participants on stage and perhaps questions from the audienc, you will need more mics of course. For the stream, if at all possible add another mixer placed outside the "arena" allowing the mixer sitting there to hear the actual sound sent to the stream. This mixer could have the camera mics connected, but my guess is that they will only make sound muddy (so not used).
Repeat for second location.
Or, if they do not run concurrent and you are a very confident person it can in theory done from one mixer. Two mic inputs (one from each stage), two line level inputs from the cameras. Three outputs: one to each set of speakers and one to stream. It will be a high work-load and takes quite a bit of experience and still have quite a bit of possibility for problems. Most mixers has one stereo output. Send, say, left channel to one stage and right channel to the other stage. Take one 'effect send' to the stream hardware. A small cheap mixer will have these inputs and outputs but will probably be less reliable and more fiddly to work with than professional level equipment.
Note that mic outputs and camera outputs work differently and need different cables and perhaps DI boxes.
My suggestion is to do a lot of rehearsals in advance. Pack everything up in your car, drive around the block, unpack everything and dry-run the full event (including streaming to closed stream groups). Ask for feedback on sound on stage as well as from streams. Practice shows what works, and what does not, adjust befor next rehearsal. A single missed cable (or too short cable) will create problems. Pack up everything in labled containers. Write down everything and sketch setups - you might become ill at the last moment and the show must go on.

How to do all of that depends on what equipment you can get. You might need an assortment of things and it changes depending on, if the two areas run simultaneously, and how close “next to each other” is. It’s not really clear… If you have everything you need besides the mixer, then auxiliary outputs are the way to send audio to multiple places.
Note: streaming audio from a microphone pointing towards a PA system (like cameras) will create issues with the audio quality
